# Error with visual part of SciChart modifiers

Tags: c#, wpf, scichart

I've written an app with using SciSchart surface with some modifiers.

```
 <s:SciChartSurface x:Name="scichartSurface"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" MouseLeftButtonDown="scichartSurface_MouseLeftButtonDown"  
                       PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="scichartSurface_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseDoubleClick="scichartSurface_MouseDoubleClick">

        <s:SciChartSurface.XAxis>
            <s:DateTimeAxis x:Name="X1" Id ="XAxis" AxisTitle="Время" SubDayTextFormatting="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
        </s:SciChartSurface.XAxis>
        <s:SciChartSurface.YAxes>
            <s:NumericAxis x:Name="Default" Id="Value" AxisTitle="Значение" AxisAlignment="Left" VisibleRange="-10, 110" Visibility="Collapsed" ToolTip="Ось безразмерных величин"/>
        </s:SciChartSurface.YAxes>
        <s:SciChartSurface.ChartModifier >
            <s:ModifierGroup x:Name="mGroup">                    
                <s:RubberBandXyZoomModifier x:Name="rubXyModifier" ExecuteOn="MouseLeftButton" IsXAxisOnly="{Binding Path=(local:SessionVariables.IsXScaleOnly), UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                            RubberBandFill="#33FFFFFF" RubberBandStroke="DarkRed" ZoomExtentsY="{Binding Path=(local:SessionVariables.IsYScaleOnly), UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                            RubberBandStrokeDashArray="2 2" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=(local:SessionVariables.IsScaleMode), UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <!-- Allow pan on Right mouse drag -->
                <s:ZoomPanModifier x:Name="zoomPanModifier" ExecuteOn="MouseLeftButton" ClipModeX="None" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=(local:SessionVariables.IsMovingMode), UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <!-- Allow Dragging YAxis to Scale -->
                <s:YAxisDragModifier x:Name="yDrag" DragMode="Pan" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=(local:SessionVariables.IsMovingMode), UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <!-- Allow Dragging XAxis to Pan -->
                <s:XAxisDragModifier x:Name="xDrag" DragMode="Pan" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=(local:SessionVariables.IsMovingMode), UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <!-- Allow Mousewheel Zoom -->
                <!--<s:MouseWheelZoomModifier IsEnabled="{Binding Path=(local:SessionVariables.IsMovingMode),Converter={local:BackBoolConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>-->
                <s:RolloverModifier ExecuteOn="MouseMove" ShowTooltipOn="Never" SourceMode="SelectedSeries" x:Name="rollModifier"/>
                <!--Реперы-->
                <s:VerticalSliceModifier x:Name="sliceModifier"/>
                <!--Курсор с перекрестьем-->
                <s:CursorModifier IsEnabled="True" ShowTooltip="True" ShowTooltipOn="Never"
                        ShowAxisLabels="True" SourceMode="AllVisibleSeries" x:Name="cursModifier"/>
                <s:TooltipModifier >

                </s:TooltipModifier>
            </s:ModifierGroup>

        </s:SciChartSurface.ChartModifier>
    </s:SciChartSurface>
```

While using this surface I get an error, occurs randomly. The error is

> The specified Visual element is already a child of another Visual
>   element or the root CompositionTarget element

Also, I've got a [StackTrace](https://dropmefiles.com/OazWo) for this error.
After analyzing it I decided that the problem is in `VerticalSliceModifierBase.AttachRolloverMarker()` method, but I've no idea about the reason. Can you help me?

Comment: SciChart is commercial software, why dont you ask them? I mean they are the best people to answer

Comment: they've got a support team here, and sometimes it's much faster to answer in SO than using them official website

Comment: Answer for this question is 'I don't know' because its not something I've seen before & don't have enough info to understand the problem. I have some more questions - does this occur in the designer only or at runtime? What version of SciChart? What version of Visual Studio? is the above code sample alone enough to reproduce this? Always or just sometimes?

Comment: @Dr.ABT, I get this error in runtime only. I use SciChart v4.2.5.10565, VS 2017 Comunity. I can't get you such code sample. This error occurs randomly. After deleting CursorModifier this error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd suggest is update.

The latest version is [SciChart v5.3.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SciChart/) which is available from NuGet.

Since version 4.2.5 SciChart has fixed hundreds of bugs since v4.2.5 released 18 months ago ([see release history](https://www.scichart.com/tag/wpf/)) and update frequency is very high. If the latest version has the problem, post a code sample on the [SciChart forums](http://www.scichart.com/questions) and it will be investigated